# How to disable SSLv3.0 and use TLS1.0 in Gunicorn

Tags: ssl, gunicorn

I am running Django 1.7 with gunicorn. I am able to use https using gunicorn by passing certificate and key file as parameter.

When I validate my server by geotrust ssl tools, it says everything is fine except -

```
This server may be vulnerable: SSLv3 is enabled
Disable SSLv3 and use TLS 1.0 or higher.
```

I am new to this and not able to understand how to do this. Is this is related to machine or this is related to gunicorn?

Comment: Use the [`ssl-version`](https://gunicorn-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings.html#ssl-version) and [`--ciphers`](https://gunicorn-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings.html#ciphers) options.

Comment: @ThomasOrozco Looks like it would be the way to do it, but do you know of any pointers to actual er... documentation on those? :) Ie. what does "stdlib ssl module’s" actually refer to?

Comment: you mean to say I need to add `--ciphers=TLSv1` and what should i use in `--ssl-version=?`

Comment: `ssl-version` is an integer that corresponds to the `PROTOCOL_*` constants from the `ssl` module in the standard library.  `ciphers` is described there as well: https://docs.python.org/2/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLContext.set_ciphers

Comment: Hi @anuragal, did you figure this one out? Based on the previous comment, I set ssl-version to 3, and ciphers to TLSv1. I'm having it tested by my security guys and will report back.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson did you make any progress on this?

Comment: @ThomasOrozco I set ssl-version=3 and --ciphers=TLSv1. However, I can still connect with the following `openssl s_client -connect myhost:8080 -cipher eNULL`.  If I set the --ciphers=HIGH, then I cannot connect with the eNULL option.

Comment: @ThomasOrozco Do you know if there is a way to request a list of legal ciphers? For example, my Nginx uses the following string:  `"EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH"`

Comment: @MatthewMoisen, this depends on the version of OpenSSL you are using (and the configuration thereof). In most cases just running `openssl ciphers` should give you that.

Answer (score 2):

gunicorn **--ssl-version TLSv1_2** -b 0.0.0.0:8000 project:app

This should enable TLSV1.2 in 8000 port. you can also check if TLSV1 is still active by running below command. if connection established, then target uses tlsv1

openssl s_client -connect hostname:port -tls1

You can also check for tlsv1.2:
openssl s_client -connect hostname:port -tls1_2

Answer (score 2):

Replying to an old thread here, in order to disable anything but TLSv1.2+ and weak ciphers, allowing to pass [SSLLabs tests](https://ssllabs.com)

Gunicorn option `--ssl-version` allows to set minimal SSL version to use.
Gunicorn `--ciphers` allows to enable / disable cipher sets or specific ciphers.
Both options accept OpenSSL standard directives.
Good cipher lists can be found on [cipherli.st](https://syslink.pl/cipherlist/)

As of April 2021, in order to have a secure SSL connection according to SSLLabs, I made the following

```
/usr/bin/gunicorn --ssl-version=TLSv1_2 --ciphers='DEFAULT:!aNULL:!eNULL:!MD5:!3DES:!DES:!RC4:!IDEA:!SEED:!aDSS:!SRP:!PSK' --certfile=/etc/pki/tls/certs/mycert.crt --keyfile=/etc/pki/tls/private/mykey.key
```

**Warning**: The singlequotes need to be removed if the commandline is to be put in a systemd unit file.