# Force gunicorn to Only Accept a Particular Cipher for SSL/TLS connections

Tags: kubernetes, ssl, curl, gunicorn, tls1.3

I have a gunicorn server containerized running in a Kubernetes cluster.
I only want the gunicorn server to respond to users that connect using the TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 cipher suite.
I can't figure out how to effectively pass the --cipher argument to restrict all non TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 ciphers.

If I start gunicorn without specifying a cipher like this

```
gunicorn --workers=2 \
--bind=0.0.0.0:443 \
--timeout 600 \
--error-logfile gunicorn.log \
--log-level debug \
--certfile ./cert.pem \
--keyfile ./key.pem \
--ssl-version=5 \
main_server:app
```

I can connect to the server just fine using curl

```
$ curl --insecure --tls13-ciphers TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 -v https://192.168.49.2/serve
*   Trying 192.168.49.2:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 192.168.49.2 (192.168.49.2) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* TLS 1.3 cipher selection: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: O=Acme Co; CN=Kubernetes Ingress Controller Fake Certificate
*  start date: Dec  5 17:21:58 2023 GMT
*  expire date: Dec  4 17:21:58 2024 GMT
*  issuer: O=Acme Co; CN=Kubernetes Ingress Controller Fake Certificate
*  SSL certificate verify result: unable to get local issuer certificate (20), continuing anyway.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x55cc709790c0)
> GET /serve HTTP/2
> Host: 192.168.49.2
> user-agent: curl/7.68.0
> accept: */*
> 
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* old SSL session ID is stale, removing
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 128)!
< HTTP/2 200 
< date: Wed, 06 Dec 2023 16:37:41 GMT
< content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< content-length: 37
< 
* Connection #0 to host 192.168.49.2 left intact
<h1><center>Hello World!</center><h1>
```

Additionally the negotiation actually picks the cipher I want by default (SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 above) so I know the server and curl both support it.

If I specify the cipher by starting gunicorn like this:

```
gunicorn --workers=2 \
--bind=0.0.0.0:443 \
--timeout 600 \
--error-logfile gunicorn.log \
--log-level debug \
--certfile ./cert.pem \
--keyfile ./key.pem \
--ssl-version=5 \
--ciphers="TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384" \
main_server:app
```

the logs for the gunicorn server give me:

```
[2023-12-06 17:51:39 +0000] [8] [DEBUG] Error processing SSL request.

[2023-12-06 17:51:39 +0000] [8] [WARNING] Invalid request from ip=10.244.0.5: ('No cipher can be selected.',)
```

and curl returns this:

```
  $ curl --insecure --tls13-ciphers TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 -v https://192.168.49.2/serve
*   Trying 192.168.49.2:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 192.168.49.2 (192.168.49.2) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* TLS 1.3 cipher selection: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: O=Acme Co; CN=Kubernetes Ingress Controller Fake Certificate
*  start date: Dec  5 17:21:58 2023 GMT
*  expire date: Dec  4 17:21:58 2024 GMT
*  issuer: O=Acme Co; CN=Kubernetes Ingress Controller Fake Certificate
*  SSL certificate verify result: unable to get local issuer certificate (20), continuing anyway.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x559bae1090c0)
> GET /serve HTTP/2
> Host: 192.168.49.2
> user-agent: curl/7.68.0
> accept: */*
> 
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* old SSL session ID is stale, removing
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 128)!
< HTTP/2 502 
< date: Wed, 06 Dec 2023 17:51:39 GMT
< content-type: text/html
< content-length: 150
< 
<html>
<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
* Connection #0 to host 192.168.49.2 left intact
```

I've tried issuing the cipher argement with double quotes, single quotes, and no quotes. I've tried with an equals sign and with a space plus the cipher name.

I know that the Kubernetes ingress and service networking is fine otherwise things wouldn't work when I don't specify the exact cipher.

I've looked https://venafi.com/blog/what-are-cipher-suites/ , https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/20.1.0/settings.html ,
https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/2579,
[How to disable SSLv3.0 and use TLS1.0 in Gunicorn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30259339/how-to-disable-sslv3-0-and-use-tls1-0-in-gunicorn),
and a few other places trying to find an example of how to force this, but haven't been able to figure out what is going on. The best I can tell I am messing up the format for the cipher.

I'm looking for an answer that will show me how to start gunicorn so that it will only respond when the requesting user tries to connect with the TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 cipher.

Answer (score 0):

OK I figured it out. For those trying to do something similar, there is a lot going on here.

1. gunicorn is relying on OpenSSL under the hood. The SSL based command line arguments that are passed to gunicorn are then used in calls to OpenSSL under the hood.
2. OpenSSL is dedicated to supporting TLS 1.3 as the spec is written which means that it has to support all the TLS 1.3 cipher suites out of the box. Additionally, OpenSSL won't accept command line arguments that limit TLS 1.3 ciphers. This is a change from previous SSL/TLS version behavior for OpenSSL
3. The Kubernetes Ingress was terminating the SSL connection from curl not passing it on to my container which meant no matter what I did to my container I couldn't limit the initial connection.

To fix the issues and force the cipher suite I wanted.

1. gunicorn - didn't have to do anything here.
2. OpenSSL - I modified the OpenSSL config files to only allow the ciphers I wanted. serverfault has a question with an answer that shows how to do this https://serverfault.com/questions/1033439/how-do-i-disable-just-one-cipher-out-of-openssl-tlsv1-3-list  they reference a blog post with more details https://dawnbringer.net/blog/1083/TLS%20All%20The%20Things!%20Perfect%20ssl-labs%20score%20for%20Nginx but the bottom line is that you need to add the following section to the openssl.conf file.

   [system_default_sect]
   MinProtocol = TLSv1.2
   CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=2
   Ciphersuites = TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
   Options = ServerPreference,PrioritizeChaCha

The modification needs to be made anywhere there is an openssl.cnf file which for my Ubuntu distro was /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf and /lib/usr/ssl/openssl.cnf. I highly encourage reading the OpenSSL config file format documentation as it helps to illuminate config requirements that aren't apparent. https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man5/config.html

3. To get the SSL handshake passed through the Ingress and to my container I had to update the Ingress controller and add the flag --enable-ssl-passthrough. Note that is the controller not the Deployment.

The Deployment had to have the following annotations

```
   nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "https"
   nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
   nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
```

Finally SSL passthrough requires that the Ingress Deployment have a host set. I was just using the IP Address for my curl commands. To fix this I added a record to /etc/hosts for the IP of the Ingress and then used the hostname I made up for the /etc/host record as the host for the Ingress Deployment.